# Two different Rest Api Spring Boot and 1 Login

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, httpcookie, spring-boot-security

I am trying to make 2 apps login with 1 auth. My App number one gonna provide JWT token in cookie and I want that my app number 2 use that cookie to serve @PreAUthrize. I have full functionality in my first App, but honestly I have no clue how to mix them together. Here is my first app auth:

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

  @Override
  public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());

    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    final Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    body.put("error", "Unauthorized");
    body.put("message", authException.getMessage());
    body.put("path", request.getServletPath());

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
  }
}
```

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired
  private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = parseJwt(request);
      if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                null,
                userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String jwt = jwtUtils.getJwtFromCookies(request);
    return jwt;
  }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${tfg.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${tfg.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    @Value("${tfg.app.jwtCookieName}")
    private String jwtCookie;


    public String getJwtFromCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, jwtCookie);
        if (cookie != null) {
            return cookie.getValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ResponseCookie generateJwtCookie(EmployeeEntity userPrincipal) {
        String jwt = generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, jwt).path("/").maxAge(30000).httpOnly(true).build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public ResponseCookie getCleanJwtCookie() {
        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from(jwtCookie, null).path("/api").build();
        return cookie;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }
}
```

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEnconderConfig passwordEnconderConfig;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEnconderConfig.passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I tried to pass this bean to my second app with al JWT stuff and obviusly provided same key, but cannot extract UserDetails and don't know how to do it.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

EDIT1: I thought maybe just extract userDetails from JWT is viable and implements that in my second app. I don´t know how to extract that, does it gives me all info I need like permission and also don´t know how to implmenets that automaticly.